# "Short series" serial downvoting?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

With a very short span of time, several of my answers and questions have been downvoted. These questions share a tag - but it's a tag on which I have well over a 100 questions. The questions are not otherwise related and aren't linked. Also, some are older and some are newer. I would consider this a serial downvoting spree for sure if I had gotten, say, 8 downvotes. But - I only got 4.

- [How can I determine whether a CUDA context is the primary one - cheaply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62867248/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-cuda-context-is-the-primary-one-cheaply)
- [Solving n linear systems efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55319498/solving-n-linear-systems-efficiently/55319560#55319560)
- [How can I list the functions in a CUDA (driver) module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62742649/how-can-i-list-the-functions-in-a-cuda-driver-module)
- [Why does CUDA have contexts-per-device rather than devices-per-context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62753316/why-does-cuda-have-contexts-per-device-rather-than-devices-per-context)

Now, two of these have gotten downvoted earlier, so I can chalk them up to "controversy", but the other two are pretty innocuous, i.e. I absolutely don't see how they would get downvoted - especially not a long while after they were asked.

My question here: How do I tell whether it's a weird fluke or a serial downvote spree? Or perhaps it can't even count as one with so few questions?

Comment: For starters, you could wait 24 hours and see if they get reversed. The reversal script knows if it's the same user downvoting, you can only guess, and afaik 4 votes is often enough to trigger it but the exact algorithm is unknown.

Comment: serial downvoters are more clever, I start getting only 3 downvotes in a row which doesn't trigger the *serial downvote* (at least based on my experience)

Comment: @TemaniAfif: If they were clever they wouldn't waste their life on serial downvoting :-(

Comment: yes, they *think* they are clever ;). As you said, they are simply wasting their time so let them do. It will hurt only them.

Comment: *Dear serial downvoters, please down vote at least 8 posts to achieve an optimal experience for all involved ...*

Comment: This sounds like serial down voting... you probably tripped someone while moderating... I had cases where user cast only single down vote for me, but then he went over other users that close voted his question and down voted them too, so it was easy to spot who was responsible.

Comment: @einpoklum Well, they're clearly wasting *your* time too... Otherwise you wouldn't be spending time wondering if something can be considered serial downvoting ;)

Comment: Wouldn't it suitable to create a feature-request so SE-Staff will look and maybe update the parameters for their voting reversal script? They don't need to publish the old or the new parameters, but they could look if the "ordinary" serial voter has adapted to the reversal tool and if they should adapt as well.

Comment: @Tom: This is not for me to say, I'm biased in favor of myself here.

Comment: Not what it looks like.  Somebody that cares a lot about the [cuda] tag staying tidy is feeding dead questions to the roomba.  Not just yours, [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63114663/cuda-occupancy-max-active-blocks-per-multiprocessor-0).  About the only practical way to moderate small tags.

Comment: @HansPassant: But two of the downvotes are on answers.

Comment: I saw one, the question was DVed as well, surely for that reason.  It was not a great answer.

Comment: @TemaniAfif It triggers at 3 downvotes for me. I suspect tag popularity has something to do with it.

Comment: @10Rep: What is "It" in your answer?

Comment: @einpoklum The CSS tag is much more active than the [tag:tkinter] tag. I didn't answer, it's just a comment.

Comment: If you feel there's an issue with voting: wait 24 hours to see if it's automatically reversed. If it's not auto-reversed after 24 hours, then raise and "in need of moderator intervention" and explain the issue. Posting on meta is definitely *not* the right way to handle it, as non-moderators *can't* do anything about it, but often try by doing inappropriate things (e.g. revenge-revenge voting). As to the voting here, it's not clear if a moderator even saw this MSO post or did so after the first 24 hours, which they would have waited for to act, as we *also* wait for the reversal script to run.